# JavaScript ASCII to text

Tags: javascript, nan

I was wondering if it's possible to change the "Batman" text in the JavaScript Batman Joke to ASCII, then convert it and have it appear in the browser

The original joke is

```
javascript:Array(16).join("lol" - 1) + "Batman"
```

can this be changed to something like

```
javascript:Array(16).join("lol" - 1) + [66, 97, 116, 109, 097, 110].forEach(function(e) { document.write(String.fromCharCode(e)); } );
```

where [66, 97, etc] are the ASCII codes for Batman. This fails because the document object does not exist in an empty browser window.

(PS Feel free to delete if this isn't appropriate, it was only for fun)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to use any sort of loop or iterator for your array, [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) will actually accept as many characters as you want to give it. So this will work just fine:

```
javascript:Array(16).join(-'.') + String.fromCharCode(66, 97, 116, 109, 097, 110);
```

However, if you wanted to call [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) for every element of the array, you can. Every JavaScript function can be called using [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) which will run the function for each array element:

```
javascript:Array(16).join("lol" - 1) + String.fromCharCode.apply(this,[66, 97, 116, 109, 097, 110]);
```

Also, the purpose of `"lol" - 1` is to try to create a bad number (a NaN or Not a Number). If you wanted to obfuscate things a bit further, you could use any math operation on a nonnumerical string. For example:

```
javascript:Array(16).join(-'.') + String.fromCharCode.apply(this,[66, 97, 116, 109, 097, 110])
```

because `-'.'` is interpenetrated as `0 - '.'` which doesn't make any sense so it its NaN.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
javascript:var str='';[66, 97, 116, 109, 097, 110].forEach(function(e) { str+= (String.fromCharCode(e)); } ); Array(16).join("lol" - 1) + str;
```

Or:

```
javascript:Array(16).join("lol" - 1) + [66, 97, 116, 109, 097, 110].map(function(e) { return (String.fromCharCode(e)); }).join('');
```